# Jquery Vertical Simple Menu

Tags: jquery, menu

Hey guys just looking for a simple Jquery menu that is vertical and that pops out horizontally.

Just simple as can be and has to be 3 levels deep i have look everywhere and there all fancy and shit which isnt suited for thsi website, it also has to be compatible with ie 6, 7 and 8.

I cant find anything anywhere that is of simple use.

Answer (score 0):

I don't want to sound mean or rude or anything, but making menus and animation effects is very easy once you have learned a bit of CSS, JavaScript and jQuery.

Try some tutorials. [Getting Started with jQuery by Jörn Zaefferer](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Getting_Started_with_jQuery) is a good read for beginners and if you have money to spend there are books like [Learning jQuery](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1847196705).

The bottom line is that jQuery (or programming in general) isn't always about finding the right components, or plugins; because sometimes you have to write your own code.

Comment: yeah i understand this, thank you very much for your input. im just trying to find something simple that is already constructed.

Comment: Well. If it doesn't exist yet, you just have to make it.